# Indicate that Organization is owned by a list of Organizations/Persons in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I have a collection of webpages, each devoted to a single Organization (e.g. a business). Each page lists entities which own that Organization (usually shareholders).

**How can I annotate the page with Schema.org markup to indicate that?**

My research:

I see that [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization) has `owns` property. What I'd ideally want is the reverse: something like `ownedBy`. I wonder if I can achieve that with some other property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a property is only defined in one direction, it [can still be used in the other direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497624/1591669).

But the [`owns`](https://schema.org/owns) property is only for owning products, not other organizations, so it’s not suitable for your case.

The [`ownershipFundingInfo`](https://pending.schema.org/ownershipFundingInfo) property (currently in Pending) allows to describe the "organizational ownership structure", but its value is a description/page, not a list of owning entities.

So, Schema.org doesn’t seem to have a property to convey that a `Person`/`Organization` owns another `Organization`.